# Ordering by formula fields in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Suppose that I have the following mapping with a `formula` property:

```
<class name="Planet" table="planets">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <!-- somefunc() is a native SQL function -->
    <property name="Distance" formula="somefunc()" />
</class>
```

I would like to get all planets and order them by the `Distance` calculated property:

```
var planets = session
    .CreateCriteria<Planet>()
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Distance"))
    .List<Planet>();
```

This is translated to the following query:

```
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc() as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY somefunc()
```

Desired query:

```
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc() as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY formula0
```

If I set a projection with an alias it works fine:

```
var planets = session
    .CreateCriteria<Planet>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Distance"), "dist"))
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("dist"))
    .List<Planet>();
```

SQL:

```
SELECT somefunc() as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY formula0
```

but it populates only the Distance property in the result and I really like to avoid projecting manually over all the other properties of my object (there could be many other properties).

Is this achievable with NHibernate? As a bonus I would like to pass parameters to the native `somefunc()` SQL function. Anything producing the desired SQL is acceptable (replacing the formula field with subselects, etc...), the important thing is to have the calculated Distance property in the resulting object and order by this distance inside SQL.

Comment: I'd just use projections...or do you need the actual Planets for further manipulation?

Comment: Yes, projections work but if later a property is added to the object I will need to add it to the projections also and if I forget it won't be assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These 2 are 100% identical in SQL. Why does it matter?

```
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc() as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY somefunc()
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc() as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY formula0
```

Edit, still the same:

The ORDER BY clause will simply repeat the SELECT func call whether aliased or not

```
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc(1, 'fish') as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY somefunc(1, 'fish')
SELECT Id as id0, somefunc(1, 'fish') as formula0 FROM planets ORDER BY formula0
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, you are correct, those queries are 100% identical. Now how do I pass parameters to the function in the OrderBy clause as my function expects parameters?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I would assume that when you pass parameters to somefunc in the SELECT clause, they would end up in the ORDER BY. See my edit please. It makes no sense to order by a different function value, does it?